# how to route ocserv traffic to wireguard split tunnel

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, tunnel, wireguard

I want to route ocserv traffic to wireguard split tunnel

here is the net flow

```bash
[ (ocserv client) ] =====> [ server A (ocserv + wg server) ] <===== [ server B (wg client) ]
```

Because wg protocol is blocked by firewall (between server A and B), wg tunnel has been made from server B to server A (a reverse tunnel).
The goal is that an ocserv client should be able to access Internet on server B (the traffic originates from server B) through wireguard split tunnel (has been made between server A and B)

#### client

- full route to ocserv (server A)

---

#### server A

- ocserv network `192.168.200.0/24`
- ocserv gateway `192.168.200.1`
- wg server `192.168.250.1/24`

##### wg server `address`

```bash
Address = 192.168.250.1/24
```

##### iptable

```bash
# source NAT
# 192.168.250.1 is wg server ip
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.0/24 -o wg_server  -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.250.1
```

##### ip route (policy based routing)

```bash
# wg_out is just an name for routing table
ip rule show table wg_out
32752:  from 192.168.200.0/24 lookup wg_out

### default route for wg_out
ip route show table wg_out
default via 192.168.250.2 dev wg_server

### 192.168.250.2
### is the wg client ip (other side of the tunnel)
```

##### tcpdump check

if ocserv client `ping -c1 1.1.1.2`

```bash
tcpdump -i any icmp and dst host 1.1.1.2

### 192.168.200.95
### ocserv client IP
17:53:01.693154 fun0  In  IP 192.168.200.95 > 1.1.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 311, seq 4, length 64

### 192.168.250.1 
### wg server IP
17:53:01.693173 wg_server Out IP 192.168.250.1 > 1.1.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 311, seq 4, length 64
```

---

#### server B

- wg client `192.168.250.2/24`

##### iptables

```bash
### allow ocserv network 
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source server-B-public-IP
```

##### ip route

allowing ocserv network to come via wg client

```bash
192.168.200.0/24 dev wg_client scope link
```

##### wg client `AllowedIPs`

```bash
AllowedIPs = 192.168.250.0/24,192.168.200.0/24
```

what should be added/changed so that ocserv client can access Internet on server B?
With this setup ocserv client has access to

- wg server `192.168.250.1`
- wg client `192.168.250.2`

but does not have access to Internet.