# why wireguard PersistentKeepalive does not work?

Tags: linux, vpn, tunnel, wireguard

I wireguard server and a single client have been setup on two VPSs to have a split tunnel in between, but every few hours, the client side connection stops and I have to restart the interface to reconnect again.

Both servers have public IP, there is no NAT or Firewalls.

server config

```bash
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***
Address = 172.31.104.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = PORT


### begin c1 ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 172.31.104.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25
### end c1 ###
```

and the client

```bash
[Interface]
Address = 172.31.104.2/32
PrivateKey = ***
DNS = 1.1.1.2,1.0.0.2


[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 172.31.104.1/24
Endpoint = IP:PORT
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

even a cron job did not help (client side)

```bash
* * * * * /usr/bin/ping  -c4  172.31.104.1
```

Comment: See if this article helps:   ............   https://learn.beako.net/books/wireguard/page/persistentkeepalive

Comment: note: If both have public IP addresses, then PersistentKeepalive has no useful role and shouldn't even be needed anywhere. There's probably an other problem.

Comment: @A.B tried adding and removing `PersistentKeepalive` the thing is if I remove it , it stops working after few minutes, but when added lasts for hours, what else can cause this ?

Comment: NAT or firewall despite what you wrote. Perhaps not directly on your systems. Or Docker running on one of the systems. etc.

Comment: For each system can you provide their network configuration while VPN works? Something like `ip link; ip -br addr; ip route; ip rule` + `nft list ruleset` (as root) + the output of `wg` (as root). You can replace public IP addresses with 1 or 2 blocks from RFC 5737: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html#section-3 . Then when it fails some minutes or hours later again the very same commands.

Comment: @A.B actually the configuration is more complex than what posted here. initially my issue was [how to route ocserv traffic to wireguard split tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/1827946/how-to-route-ocserv-traffic-to-wireguard-split-tunnel) -- I solved that but faced this issue of random disconnections -- I did some changes and will wait for another 24h -- if did not help -- inform you here -- thank you -- and RFC 5737 was useful I did not know that